# How can I set the points outside of the certain range to 0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have interpolated a plot and extended the x and y which gave me the following contour plot. How can I rearrange the Z matrix so that the points outside the red box are 0.

```
x=data.columns.astype('float64')
y=data.index.to_numpy()
z=data.to_numpy() 
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

ratio = 4
x_new = x*ratio
y_new=y*ratio
#plt.plot(x_new,y_new)

f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')
z_new = f(x_new, y_new)
X_new,Y_new = np.meshgrid(x_new, y_new)

plt.contourf(X_new, Y_new, znew, alpha = 1, cmap=plt.cm.inferno)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example, which should be easy to adapt to your case.
The `np.where` function is your friend here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-15, 15, 301)
y = np.linspace(-15, 5, 201)

X_new, Y_new = np.meshgrid(x, y)

znew = np.random.randn(*X_new.shape)

znew = np.where((X_new > 5) & (X_new < 10) & 
                (Y_new > -2) & (Y_new < 2), znew, 0)

plt.contourf(X_new, Y_new, znew, alpha = 1, cmap=plt.cm.inferno)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very close but it sets all the values for z to zero. Here is the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3K1bjc3D8iB8cXZui5Z05yRzQueqGj-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean it sets all the value for z to zero? I'm afraid I cannot download your full dataset. The way questions are typically posted is by providing a minimal reproducible example, using some toy data like the random array in my answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have just rearranged the case and did for index like this : idx = (X < X_max) & (X > X_min) &(Y < Y_max) & (Y > Y_min)
X[~idx] = 0
Y[~idx] = 0